# Example has no errors but won't generate Swing JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, netbeans-7

I'm learning Java and would like to do the tutorials I found at http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/basics/

For the first tutorial when I run in Netbeans I get no errors and a window doesn't show up. Is there a setting I need to set in Netbeans?

```
package tut01;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Tut01 extends JFrame{

    public Tut01(){
        add(new Board());
        setTitle("Tut01");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(300, 280);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Tut01();
    }
}


package tut01;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Board extends JPanel{
    public Board(){
    }
}
```

Comment: what netbeans prints to console ?

Comment: That tutorial does not follow basic conventions like calling GUI methods from the Event Dispatch Thread... Not good...

Comment: Why was it down voted? @assylias then can you point me to a better one?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I am not new to programming nor the IDE and I have done basic Java making mods for minecraft etc. I'm new but not that new to Java.

Comment: @yamikoWebs like this SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new Tut01();            }
        });

Comment: @SergiiZagriichuk same result.

Comment: @AndrewThompson This is a site for helping people not bashing against them. and yes there is a lot to using my IDE with Java I don't know since I only done mods with Java. Thats why I'm asking for help. I mainly use it for PHP. I found the problem and I cant just run the build I have to clean and build first.

Comment: @SergiiZagriichuk I'm using windows 8 x64 right now

Comment: I've retest on Windows 8 all is working, try to download new version of netbeans and JDK re-install all, and try again this code.

Answer (score 1):

One possible problem is that you need to call all GUI-related code [on the UI thread (EDT)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) - try this to see if it works better:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new Tut01();
        }
    });
}
```

Once you have done that, in Netbeans, go to the `Tut01.java` file and press SHIFT+F6 to run that program (if you simply press F6 you might be running something else).

A [good tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) can be found on Oracle's website.

Note: your code works with or without that change on my machine.